# SLIM framework rest API error in sending email

Tags: rest, slim

i am designing REST API using SLIM framework. i want to send email in php.

i have write mailing.php which is sending email very accurately.

but whenever i call that mailing.php from my REST API of slim framework. then this following error occurs .

```
Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details:

Message: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated
File: C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Mail.php
Line: 154
Stack Trace:

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\CC\mailing.php(2): Slim::handleErrors(8192, 'Assigning the r...', 'C:\xampp\php\PE...', 154, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\CC\mailing.php(2): require_once()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\CC\waist.php(2): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\CC\testingnew.php(545): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#4 [internal function]: {closure}()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\CC\Slim\Route.php(392): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\CC\Slim\Slim.php(1051): Slim_Route->dispatch()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\CC\testingnew.php(771): Slim->run()
#8 {main}
```

please suggest me what should i do to remove this error. in any doubt then feel free to ask me. I really need your help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're having some sort of reference assignment, this is deprecated in PHP5.

You can't use:

```
$foo =& new MyClass();
```

Please provide some more code so we can see what's wrong.